# UNION SELECT with Joining of two other related tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query which works. It searches the accounts table and returns results by relevance rank.

```
SELECT id, name, phone_office, sum( relevance )
FROM (
           SELECT id, name, phone_office, 10 AS relevance
           FROM accounts
           WHERE (
              IF( LENGTH( '{$name}' ) >0, name LIKE '%{$name}%', 0 )
           )
           AND deleted = '0'

           UNION

           SELECT id, name, phone_office, 5 AS relevance
           FROM accounts
           WHERE phone_office LIKE '%{$phone}%'
           AND deleted = '0'

           UNION

           SELECT id, name, phone_office, 2 AS relevance
           FROM accounts
           WHERE billing_address_postalcode LIKE '%{$postal_code}%'
           AND deleted = '0'
) results
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY sum( relevance ) DESC
```

I also need search by email address.

The problem is I need to add in another `UNION SELECT` that joins the email address tables. In this application the accounts email address is not stored in the accounts table its stored in its own email_addresses table which is linked to the accounts table by another table called email_addr_bean_rel.

email_addr_bean_rel has the following relevent fields

id, email_address_id, bean_id, bean_module

In my case bean_id is the id of the account and email_address_id is the id of the email address row in the email_addresses table.

This is my attempt so far:

```
 SELECT id as main_id, name, phone_office, sum(relevance)
 FROM (
    SELECT id, name, phone_office, 10 AS relevance
    FROM accounts
    WHERE (
      IF(LENGTH( '{$name}' ) > 0, name LIKE '%{$name}%', 0)
    )
    AND deleted = '0'

    UNION

    SELECT id, name, phone_office, 5 AS relevance
    FROM accounts
    WHERE phone_office LIKE '%{$phone}%'
    AND deleted = '0' 

    UNION

    SELECT id as ac, name, phone_office, 3 AS relevance
    FROM accounts
    JOIN email_addr_bean_rel eb ON (ac = eb.bean_id)
    JOIN email_addresses ea ON ( ea.id = eb.email_address_id )
    WHERE ea.email_address LIKE '%{$email}%'
    AND accounts.deleted = '0' AND eb.deleted =0 

    UNION

    SELECT id, name, phone_office, 2 AS relevance
    FROM accounts
    WHERE billing_address_postalcode LIKE '%{$postal_code}%'
    AND deleted = '0') results
 GROUP BY main_id
 ORDER BY sum( relevance ) DESC
```

I am getting column id ambiguous errors but I am also not sure how to structure the joining of the email tables correctly.

Ok after some help below I now have this:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (

          SELECT accounts.id, name, phone_office, email_address, Sum(
          CASE
          WHEN Length( 'sdfsdfsd' ) >0
          AND name LIKE '%sdfsdfsd%'
          THEN 10
          WHEN phone_office LIKE '%222-055-9034%'
          THEN 5
          WHEN email_address LIKE '%test@test.com%'
          THEN 8
          WHEN billing_address_postalcode LIKE '%12345 6789%'
          THEN 2
       END ) AS relevance
    FROM accounts
    JOIN email_addr_bean_rel eb ON ( accounts.id = eb.bean_id )
    JOIN email_addresses ea ON ( ea.id = eb.email_address_id )
    WHERE accounts.deleted = '0'
GROUP BY accounts.id
ORDER BY relevance DESC
) AS temp
WHERE temp.relevance IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Probably not very efficient but its the only way i could get it to work without returning a bunch of null rows for relevance in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Your query would be much more simply written as:

```
SELECT id, name, phone_office, sum( relevance )
FROM (SELECT id, name, phone_office,
             (CASE WHEN LENGTH( '{$name}' ) >0 AND name LIKE '%{$name}%' THEN 10 
                   WHEN phone_office LIKE '%{$phone}%' THEN 5
                   WHEN  billing_address_postalcode LIKE '%{$postal_code}%' THEN 2
              END) AS relevance
      FROM accounts
      WHERE deleted = '0'
     ) results
WHERE relevance IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY sum( relevance ) DESC ;
```

This can then be simplified to not use the subquery:

```
SELECT id, name, phone_office,
       sum(CASE WHEN LENGTH( '{$name}' ) >0 AND name LIKE '%{$name}%' THEN 10 
                WHEN phone_office LIKE '%{$phone}%' THEN 5
                WHEN  billing_address_postalcode LIKE '%{$postal_code}%' THEN 2
           END) AS relevance
FROM accounts
WHERE deleted = '0'
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY relevance DESC ;
```

With this version, an additional `JOIN` should be easy.

Comment: Just to point out the email address has to be given a relevance like others.

Comment: Ok I think I have it but its showing null rows for relevance and 'WHERE accounts.deleted = '0' AND relevance IS NOT NULL' is not working its saying Unknown column 'relevance' in 'where clause'

Comment: @user794846 . . . Neither of the queries have the condition `WHERE accounts.deleted = '0' AND relevance IS NOT NULL`.  In the first, the two conditions are split between the subquery and the outer query.